# How to draw a hatched three quarter circle or Arc

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to use `matplotlib.patches` to plot a hatched three-quarter circle (shown below)?

[image]

I tried and I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show your code (you should edit your question to include your attempt), but this is fairly straightforward using [`matplotlib.patches.Wedge`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Wedge.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
w = Wedge((0,0), 10, 90, 360, fill=False, hatch="\\", edgecolor="tab:green")
ax.add_patch(w)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

[image]